# Detect which activity will be selected in UIActivityViewController

Tags: ios, uiactivityviewcontroller

I plan to use UIActivityViewController to share text to twitter, etc. I need to share different text to twitter, email, etc. As a result, I need to change text dynamically based on user selection. May I know a way to do?

I know a way like this. But it is only after action is done and I can't change text. 
[UIActivityViewController - is there a way to know which activity was selected?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14149532/uiactivityviewcontroller-is-there-a-way-to-know-which-activity-was-selected)

Comment: your  link is clearly shows the answer then what the problem u are faced.

Comment: It is because it only show after user tap on activity. I need to change text depending on what user tap (facebook? twitter?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can implement an `UIActivityItemSource` and its `itemForActivityType:` method to provide content to match the user's selection.

This is explained [on NSHipster](http://nshipster.com/uiactivityviewcontroller/). For your convenience I copy/pasted the relevant Objective-C code and description:

> One example of how this could be used is to customize a message, depending on whether it's to be shared on Facebook or Twitter.

```
if ([activityType isEqualToString:UIActivityTypePostToFacebook]) {
    return NSLocalizedString(@"Like this!",nil);
} else if ([activityType isEqualToString:UIActivityTypePostToTwitter]) {
    return NSLocalizedString(@"Retweet this!",nil);
} else {
    return nil;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. it is perfect.

Comment: one issue its . all after work done i want to tetect when select before complitation