# Understanding Which Activity Gets Called in Sharing SwiftUI

Tags: swiftui, uiactivity

On my share sheet I see those activities but I want to understand and fetch which activity is selected to share the url.

For example, if WhatsApp is selected I want to fetch WhatsApp selected bool somehow.

```
    struct ShareSheet: UIViewControllerRepresentable {
    typealias Callback = (_ activityType: UIActivity.ActivityType?, _ completed: Bool, _ returnedItems: [Any]?, _ error: Error?) -> Void
    
    let activityItems: [Any]
    let applicationActivities: [UIActivity]? = nil
    let excludedActivityTypes: [UIActivity.ActivityType]? = nil
    let callback: Callback? = nil
    
    func makeUIViewController(context: Context) -> UIActivityViewController {
        let controller = UIActivityViewController(
            activityItems: activityItems,
            applicationActivities: applicationActivities)
        controller.excludedActivityTypes = excludedActivityTypes
        controller.completionWithItemsHandler = callback
        return controller
    }
    
    func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: UIActivityViewController, context: Context) {
        // nothing to do here
    }
}
```

What I am trying is

```
 func fetchActivity() {
    if activityItems.description == "whatsapp" {
        self.service.articleShare(article_id: articlePost.article_id, share_type: "whatsapp")
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: This might answer your question. You have to modify the completion handler https://stackoverflow.com/a/33966954/8700044

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    struct ShareSheet: UIViewControllerRepresentable {
    @ObservedObject var service = ArticleService()
    var articlePost: Article
    typealias Callback = (_ activityType: UIActivity.ActivityType?, _ completed: Bool, _ returnedItems: [Any]?, _ error: Error?) -> Void
    
    let activityItems: [Any]
    let applicationActivities: [UIActivity]? = nil
    let excludedActivityTypes: [UIActivity.ActivityType]? = nil
    let callback: Callback? = nil
    func makeUIViewController(context: Context) -> UIActivityViewController {
        let controller = UIActivityViewController(
            activityItems: activityItems,
            applicationActivities: applicationActivities)
        controller.excludedActivityTypes = excludedActivityTypes
        controller.completionWithItemsHandler = callback
        controller.completionWithItemsHandler = { activity, success, items, error in
            if !success{
                print("cancelled")
                return
            }
            if activity == UIActivity.ActivityType.postToTwitter {
                print("twitter")
                print(articlePost.article_id)
                self.service.articleShare(article_id: articlePost.article_id, share_type: "twitter")
            }
            if activity == UIActivity.ActivityType.postToFacebook {
                print("facebook")
                self.service.articleShare(article_id: articlePost.article_id, share_type: "facebook")
            }
            if activity == UIActivity.ActivityType.mail {
                print("mail")
                print(articlePost.article_id)
                self.service.articleShare(article_id: articlePost.article_id, share_type: "mail")
            }
            if activity == UIActivity.ActivityType.message {
            }
        }
        return controller
    }
    
    func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: UIActivityViewController, context: Context) {
        // nothing to do here
    }
}
```